# Add or remove class from ReactJs component

Tags: css, reactjs, components

I have some polygons and I need to play with their fill-opacity css property.

```
render() {
    const opacity = this.props.disableOpacity ? 'transparent' : 'solid';
    const classes = `${opacity} opacity`;

    return (
        <div className={'ZoneLayer'}>
            {
                this.zones.map(zone => {
                    return (
                        <Polygon key={zone['id']}
                                 positions={zone['coordinates']}
                                 color={zone['available'] ? "#6dfdae" : "#dddddd"}
                                 className={classes}
                        >
                            <Tooltip direction={"top"} sticky={true} className={"zone-tooltip"}>
                                <span>{zone['text']}</span>
                            </Tooltip>
                        </Polygon>
                    );

                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

And I use these CSS

```
.solid {
    fill-opacity: 1 !important;
}

.transparent {
    fill-opacity: 0.4;
}
```

The class is loaded initially and CSS apply properly but there are no dynamic in-app changes after changing state.

Comment: It do not seem like the CSS classes are the same as you use in the component? :S

Comment: Ups, this is a typo. I change this in question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, there is react-leaflet builtIn property **`fillOpacity`**

So I need only to change that property.

```
  render() {
        return (
            <div className={'ZoneLayer'}>
                {
                    this.zones.map(zone => {
                        return (
                            <Polygon key={zone['id']}
                                     positions={zone['coordinates']}
                                     color={zone['available'] ? "#6dfdae" : "#dddddd"}
                                     fillOpacity={this.props.disableOpacity ? 0.4 : 1}
                            >
                                <Tooltip direction={"top"} sticky={true} className={"zone-tooltip"}>
                                    <span>{zone['text']}</span>
                                </Tooltip>
                            </Polygon>
                        );

                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are dependent on props for classes value change. You need to change props from parent components or save the disableOpacity value in state of the current component. Note: if props are changing everytime your code will work fine